# “ . . . [N]ot . . . “ in Sentences, Phrases(?)?

Tags: phrases

> “There should be so much more, **not of orange**, of words . . . “
>
> “ . . . further out than you thought
>   **And not waving but drowning**. . . . “

May you call these adverbial phrases? Or, may you call them parenthetical?

Comment: *I want more of this, **not of that**.*    It's a supplemental predicate complement, IMO. *I want more of this [and] not [more] of that*.

Comment: May, maybe, “ . . . supplemental([s]?) . . . “ seem like parentheticals?

Comment: I don't think so. Parenthetical example:   I would like a raise in salary and, *now that we are discussing it*, a much longer vacation.  A parenthetical is divorced from the syntax of the matrix, whereas an additional or supplemental complement plugs into it. Do you see how `[more]` is carried over from the matrix?

Comment: I have no idea what your first example is trying to say, but the second example I would understand to mean that [someone is] "further out than you thought [and is] not waving but drowning". We have two subject complements there, *x* and *y*:  Someone is {x} and [someone is] {y}